# Start Server in windows powershell in cuba-plattform

Tags: cuba-platform

is it possible to change the cuba configuration to start tomcat server in a windows power shell window and not in a dos window?

regards
Karl

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shell script that will be invoked instead of `cmd.exe /c ...` when Studio starts the application server. The path to the script should be specified in the `CUBA_TOMCAT_START_SCRIPT` environment variable.

See the [CUBA Gradle plugin code](https://github.com/cuba-platform/cuba-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/CubaStartTomcat.groovy#L43) for details.